# Cleanup: unanswered questions from 2011

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, cleanup

There are only <s>**40**</s> **6** questions left from 2011 that have no upvoted answers.  To view these questions navigate to [Unanswered -> Newest](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest), then navigate to the last page.  Since there are so few left, here is the list:

- [Subdomain still times out after being set up a month ago](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15046/subdomain-still-times-out-after-set-up-a-month-ago)
- [AdWords: how to optimize for only one or two conversion types?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18059/adwords-how-to-optimize-for-only-one-or-two-conversion-types)
- [With Google DFP (Small Business) is it possible to disable AdSense in an Ad Slot on a per-request basis?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18875/with-google-dfp-small-business-is-it-possible-to-disable-adsense-in-an-ad-slot)
- [AdSense blocking by category: the numbers don't add up?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19427/adsense-blocking-by-category-the-numbers-dont-add-up)
- [What are differences between sell side platforms (Admeld) and self-serve platform (AdReady)?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20553/what-are-differences-between-sell-side-platforms-admeld-and-self-serve-platfor)
- [How do I set "Starting at : $12" value for a Grouped product in Magento?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22660/how-do-i-set-starting-at-12-value-for-a-grouped-product-in-magento)

Here are the ways that you can help?

- **Write a new answer** -- This is the most obvious contribution, especially if the question doesn't have any answers already.  The question would then be removed from the list when somebody upvotes your answer.
- **Upvote an existing answer** -- If the question already has a good answer, then upvote that answer.  (**5 of the 6 questions currently have an answer with no up vote**)
- **Edit the question** -- An old question might not have an answer  because of spelling, grammar, or clarity problems.  Editing such a question may allow somebody else to answer it.
- **Flag the question for closing** -- Old unanswered questions are likely not to be good questions.  Many should be closed.  An old question might commonly be closed for reasons such as:

  - "Unclear what you are asking"
  - "I can't reproduce this problem"
  - "This question isn't going to help anybody at this point"

In some cases the questions may be answered in the comments.  In those cases, it is perfectly fine to create an answer yourself that gives credit to the commentators. You should make your answer a "community wiki" answer.

Comment: What should i do if i find a correct answer in comment section and if the user who asked that question mentioned that answer as good in the comment section itself?

Comment: Put the comment into an answer and give credit to the author of the comment.

Comment: I'd be tempted to suggest that even as later than 2012 would be fine. There's a reason why a lot of questions are un-answerable even if they are fit per rules say.

Comment: @bybe Can you edit that comment for clarity?

Comment: If you're not adding to or improving the comment, it should be marked as `community wiki` as Stephen did [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18661/magento-unable-to-access-remote-site-but-able-to-access-a-simple-index-html-fi)